# Default edit application

Tags: c#

Trying to open an image for editing in C#

I can open the file with

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileItem.Path);
```

This seems to issue the default open command which in my case for jpg files is standard preview, is there any way to use Process to open the file with the associated "Edit" command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Verb`-Property of the `ProcessStartInfo`class

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb.aspx)

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("myfile.jpg");
startInfo.Verb = "edit";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: thans for your answer , not sure how this would work though. If i try to find verbs for filetype there is only Open. Not sure im doing right , could you point me to some sample